# What is the probability that there more rabbits than chickens in each of these three cages?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have $4$ chickens and $12$ rabbits, and put them into $3$ cages. What is the probability that there more rabbits than chickens in each of these three cages?

I was trying to solve it by using P(more rabbits than chicken) = 1-P(more chicken than rabbits). Since the number of chickens is far less than the number of rabbits and it would be easier to calculate.

Then, the cardinality of the sample space would be $3^{12+4}$. But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You could consider cases depending on the distribution of chickens.  Since the partitions of $4$ into at most three parts are \begin{align*} 4 & = 4\\ & = 3 + 1\\ & = 2 + 2\\ & = 2 + 1 + 1 \end{align*} you can consider whether all four rabbits are placed in a single cage, three rabbits are placed in one cage and one rabbit is placed in another, two rabbits each are placed in two of the cages, or two rabbits are placed in one cage with one rabbit placed in each of the other cages.

Comment: I think you should consider the rabbits are the same. And the chickens are the same. So, the cardinality of your sample space would become smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Reader: As discussed in the comments, and as @Matthew Pilling explained in the comments, my solution probably have an issue (read comments provided by @Matthew Pilling). I cannot delete my answer since it has been already accepted.

==============================================================

Assumptions: Chickens are indistinguishable as well as Rabbits.

Note:  For the case of distinguishable items, look at the other answer provided by @John L.

Let's say $c_{i}$ and $r_{i}$ are, respectively, the number of chickens and rabits in cage $i-th$. Therefore:

$$  c_{1} + c_{2} + c_{3} = 4  $$
$$  r_{1} + r_{2} + r_{3} = 12  $$

However, we want the number of rabbits to be more than the number of chickens in each cage. So,

$$ r_{1} = c_{1} + a_{1} + 1 $$
$$ r_{2} = c_{2} + a_{2} + 1 $$
$$ r_{3} = c_{3} + a_{3} + 1 $$

Where, $a_{i}$ is the auxiliary variable: $ a_{i} \ge 0 $

Finally, by substitution, we'll have:

$$  c_{1} + c_{2} + c_{3} = 4  $$
$$  a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} = 5  $$

So, we can first distribute the chickens and put them in cages, and then for each case, we can choose a different set of $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$, and $a_{3}$.

The final answer is:

$$ {4+3-1 \choose 3-1}{5+3-1 \choose 3-1} = {6 \choose 2}{7 \choose 2}  = 315 $$

Now, you have the number of ways putting chickens and rabits to satisfy condition. Divide it by total cases and you will get the probability.

For total number of cases:

$$  c_{1} + c_{2} + c_{3} = 4  $$
$$  r_{1} + r_{2} + r_{3} = 12  $$

total number of cases (no condition) =
$$ {4+3-1 \choose 3-1}{12+3-1 \choose 3-1} = {6 \choose 2}{14 \choose 2} = 1365 $$

$$ probaility = \frac{315}{1365} $$

Comment: The $\binom{21}{5}$ cases you counted are not equally likely to occur.  There are $\binom{16}{6}\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{5}$ ways to place six animals in the first cage, five animals in the second cage, and five animals in the third cage.  However, there is only one way to place all $16$ animals in the first cage.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Correct. I will edit it. I should do it separately (one time distributing chicken and one time distributing rabbits, with no conditions). I think it should be correct now. Right?

Comment: Your underestimate the fact that rabbits as well as chickens are distinguishable.

Comment: @user You are right. My solution is based on the assumption that they are the same since I thought it might be hard to distinguish them

Comment: As I learned from @lulu, ths patterns counted by stars and bars are not equiprobable, and I don't think your strategy can be revived. Consider distributing two indistinguishable balls into two bins. The probability that each bin contains exactly one ball is $1/2$. The probability that the first bin contains two balls is $1/4$. The probability that the second contains two balls is $1/4$. By the way, I did not downvote this answer. I think it was a great attempt.

Comment: @ Matthew Piling: Thanks for the feesback. Quick thought: If we have two balls that are indistinguishable, then we have three cases: either they are in different bins, or they are both in bin 1 or they are both in bin 2. So, out of three cases, there is only one case that each bin has only one ball (probability is 1/3) and aslo there is 1/3 probability that both balls are in first bin and 1/3 Probability both balls in second bin. Could you please let me know if I I am missing something here?

Comment: Unfortunately neglecting the fact that the objects are distinguishable invalidates your result.

Comment: Imagine having two indistibguishable balls in front of you and you tag each ball with either a "1" or a "2". The probability that you tag both balls with a "1" equals $1/4$.

Comment: @user Agreed. You are right.

Comment: @ Matthew Piling: so, based on your example, I can either see one ball with tag 1 one ball with tag2. Or both balls with tag1 or both balls wifh tag 2. Again 3 cases, each with 1/3 probability. And I know that I cannot put tag1&tag2 on the same ball since I cannot put an animal in cage 1 and at the same time in cage 2. I think I am missing something. You mentioned an example about stars and bars. Could you please provide me with a link for that example from @ lulu.

Comment: @user: I added assumption and note to clarify my answer. Thanks

Comment: @Matthew Pilling: Ohh...Now I understand. Thanks for being patient :). So, you said my answer is not corect. Do you know the crrect approach?

Comment: The probability that you tag the first and second ball with "1" is $1/2 \cdot 1/2=1/4$, not $1/3$. Also, the post I'm referring to has since been deleted. But I made a similar assumption about the patterns counted by stars and bars and it led to an incorrect answer. Think about it like this instead. You form a two digit number by selecting digits from the set $\{1,2\}$ with replacement. What is the probabolity that the number formed is $11$? What is the probability that the number formed is $22$? What is the probability that number formed is either $12$ or $21$?

Comment: @Matthew Pilling: I am almost new here. I don't know what to do. Can I delete the post? Or just add a note?

Comment: The post may attract downvotes which could jeopardize your reputation, so you may want to delete it. It's your call. I still think it was a good attempt, though. And no, I don't know of a safe way to approach this problem. After my own stars and bars failed approach to solve a problem like this I tend to tred lightly around combos unless I'm 100 percent sure in my own strategy.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I might put a note and refer the readers here to read comments, so they don't make this mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $C_i$ and $R_i$ be the number of chickens and rabbits in cage $i$.

$$P[C_1=i_1,C_2=i_2]={4\choose{i_1}}{{4-i_1}\choose{i_2}}\left(\frac{1}3 \right)^4$$
$$i_1,i_2,i_1+i_2 \in (0,1,2,3,4)$$
and
$$P[R_1=j_1,R_2=j_2]={12\choose{j_1}}{{12-j_1}\choose{j_2}}\left(\frac{1}3 \right)^{12}$$
$$j_1,j_2,j_1+j_2 \in (0,1,2,3,...,12)$$

Then, note that $12-j_1-j_2>4-i_1-i_2 \implies 7+i_1+i_2-j_1\ge j_2$.
So,
$$P[R_1>C_1,R_2>C_2,12-R_1-R_2>4-C_1-C_2]$$
$$=\sum_{i_1=0}^4 \sum_{i_2=0}^{4-i_1} \sum_{j_1=i_1+1}^{12} \sum_{j_2=i_2+1}^{7+i_1+i_2-j_1}P[C_1=i_1,C_2=i_2]P[R_1=j_1,R_2=j_2]$$
$$=\frac{112706}{177147}\approx 0.636$$

```
p[i1_, i2_, r1_, r2_] = 
 Binomial[4, i1] Binomial[4 - i1, i2] Binomial[12, j1] Binomial[12 - j1, j2]/
(3^4 3^12)

Sum[p[i1, i2, j1, j2], {i1, 0, 4}, {i2, 0, 4 - i1}, 
{j1, i1 + 1, 12}, {j2, i2 + 1, 7 + i1 + i2 - j1}]
112706/177147

N[%]
0.636229
```

Comment: This solution is for distinguishable rabbits and chickens. Right? Great approach.